# How use random choice with two lists

Tags: python

Is there a way how to use random.choice add a number to one of two lists? Making it more clear, this is my code so far:

```
 mylist_pos = []
 mylist_neg = []

 if score > 0:
    mylist_pos.append(str(score) + 'positive')
 elif score < 0:
    mylist_neg.append(str(score) + 'negative')
 else:
    n = [mylist_pos, mylist_neg]
    add_zero = random.choice(n)
    add_zero.append(score)
```

I want to add numbers > 0 to mylist_pos, all number < 0 to mylist_neg and numbers == 0 should be randomly assigned to one of the two lists, so that it either become part of mylist_pos or mylist_neg. I tried it with random.choice, but something is wrong with my syntax. :/ Has someone an idea whats wrong with me code?
Thanks!

Comment: Show us the complete error message you got. Your syntax looks fine to me. Did you forget to actually `import random`?

Comment: The code you have is completely valid syntax, if you are getting a SyntaxError you need to show more of the entire code.

Comment: Also check the indentation. It must be 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs ok on my end, however this line in your else block would also randomly assign `0` to either list. Make sure to `import random`.

```
mylist_neg.append(0) if random.choice([True, False]) else mylist_pos.append(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine for me.  Here's how I filled it out to test:

```
import random
mylist_pos = []
mylist_neg = []

for score in [-3, 3, 2, -2, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]:
    if score > 0:
       mylist_pos.append(str(score) + 'positive')
    elif score < 0:
       mylist_neg.append(str(score) + 'negative')
    else:
       n = [mylist_pos, mylist_neg]
       print "n =", n
       add_zero = random.choice(n)
       add_zero.append(score)

print mylist_pos
print mylist_neg
```

Output:

```
n = [['3positive', '2positive', '1positive'], ['-3negative', '-2negative', '-1negative']]
n = [['3positive', '2positive', '1positive', 0], ['-3negative', '-2negative', '-1negative']]
n = [['3positive', '2positive', '1positive', 0], ['-3negative', '-2negative', '-1negative', 0]]
n = [['3positive', '2positive', '1positive', 0], ['-3negative', '-2negative', '-1negative', 0, 0]]
n = [['3positive', '2positive', '1positive', 0], ['-3negative', '-2negative', '-1negative', 0, 0, 0]]
['3positive', '2positive', '1positive', 0, 0]
['-3negative', '-2negative', '-1negative', 0, 0, 0]
```